# Can't read custom file from NSInputStream

Tags: ios, objective-c, ftp, nsstream, nsinputstream

I am trying to read a custom file from my documents directory via NSInputStream to upload it to a FTP server. I'm using the exact same code as demonstrated in the [SimpleFTPSample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/simpleftpsample/introduction/intro.html) provided by Apple. It seems to work fine as long as the file is empty, but as soon as it contains data it fails.

Here's my code. This is how I create the input stream, I tried it both ways:

```
//Approach one: Init with path
self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFileAtPath:filePath];

//Approach two: Init with data
NSData* fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
self.fileStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:fileData];
```

If I init the stream with data, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` when invoking `read` on the stream (code snipped below), if I use the path it jumps right to `File read error`.

`filePath` is `@"/var/mobile/Applications/94292A2A-37FC-4D8E-BDA6-A26963932AE6/Documents/1395576645.cpn"`, `NSData` returns properly and has 806 bytes.

That's part of the `stream:handleEvent:` delegate method:

```
if (self.bufferOffset == self.bufferLimit) {
         NSInteger   bytesRead;
         bytesRead = [self.fileStream read: self.buffer maxLength: kSendBufferSize];

         if (bytesRead == -1) {
            if (kPrintsToConsole) NSLog(@"File read error");
         } else if (bytesRead == 0) {
            [self stopSending];
         } else {
            self.bufferOffset = 0;
            self.bufferLimit  = bytesRead;
         }
}
```

I'm kinda stuck. Hope you guys can help me out. Running iOS 7.1 & Xcode 5.1

Answer (score 2):

you need to call [self.fileStream open] before read. For both file and data approaches.